# Annotations in javax.annotation package in Java SE

Tags: java

What is the purpose of JSR-250 annotations in Java SE environment?

How to make use of them in a non-spring and non-java-ee environment?

Answer (score 2):

The @Annotation facility in Java was initially developed for usage in the Java Enterprise (EE/J2EE) context. It fundamentally differs whether a Java class is stateless, thereby initialized again with each user session (thread), or a singleton class with one particular state, common to all users. Clearly, this distinction is necessary in a multi-user setting of a web-application. During the course of development of Java EE, several new annotation types were added, and the workings of some annotations were changed.

The @Annotation API allows the definition of user-defined annotations, useful for Content Dependent Injection (CDI), during start-up of a Java-application. For a tutorial on the usage of annotations in CDI, see [annotation-HowTo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13236348/create-my-own-annotation-java/44465809#44465809).

The @Annotation API implements formal semantics for compilation, deployment and (JNDI) linking of Java classes. However, as the development of JPA has shown, the @Anniotation API can be extended with useful parameters that configure the way entities are managed, or other semantic directives.

At present, I'm implementing a semantics for application logic, using extensive newly defined @Annotations, including different parameters (*methods* in the @interface-file). I will later report here regarding the progress of this project.

Comment: Nice answer :), plus one